# Can anybody please explain me the meaning of this statement written in Python?

Tags: python

```
req = urllib2.Request(
    "".join(
        url[i].replace(' ', '%20') if i > url.find('?') else url[i]
        for i in xrange(len(url))
    ),
    data,
    _headers
)
```

I am new to Python. Please simplify this code for me.

Comment: You truncated something off the front of the generator expression.

Comment: I have added the whole statement now.

Comment: I've added in some line breaks so that the line is at least *vaguely* readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[f(url[i]) for i in xrange(len(url))]` is an antipattern in Python. (`xrange(len(x))` is something you should pretty much never write.) It's basically doing something to each character of the URL (assuming `url` to be a string). You should instead use something more like `[f(char) for char in url]`, or if an index is necessary, use `enumerate`.

`"".join(…)` means that for an iterable of characters `…` they will be joined with nothing (`""`) between them.

Thus,

```
url = ''.join(
        char.replace(' ', '%20') if i > url.find('?') else char
        for i, char in enumerate(url)
    )
```

That part is a dodgy way of replacing spaces () with `%20` in the query string only (after the `?` symbol).

Breaking it down, we have a generator expression, `(a for b in c)`, and as the expression of the generator, `char.replace(' ', '%20') if i > url.find('?') else char`, which means "if `i` is greater than `url.find('?')`, then use `char.replace(' ', '%20')`, otherwise use `char`.

As a simple example of what it's *doing*, if `url` was `foo bar?baz quux`, we would end up with `foo bar?baz%20quux`—the space after the `?` is replaced with `%20`.

Retaining the same functionality, this could also be written by using `str.partition` and `str.replace` more succinctly and efficiently:

```
>>> url = 'foo bar?baz quux'
>>> lhs, pivot, rhs = url.partition('?')
>>> lhs + pivot + rhs.replace(' ', '%20')
'foo bar?baz%20quux'
```

What's left is then straightforward and requires no explanation as the docs explain it:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, _headers)
```

Comment: +1. It might be worth mentioning that the non-janky way of HTML-escaping a string is with `urllib.quote`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is m trying to rewrite using for loop to make you better understand:

```
  ls = list()
  url = 'https://www.facebook.com/?ref=here is me'
  for i in range(len(url)):
      # all the element after '?'
      if i > url.find('?'):
          ls.append(url[i].replace(' ', '%20'))
      else:
          ls.append(url[i])

  nurl = ''.join(ls)
  # nurl = https://www.facebook.com/?ref=here%20is%20me
  req = urllib2.Request(nurl, data, _headers)
```